# Stuck on the second part of a double integral

Tags: integration

I'm finishing an exercise where we need to calculate  $\iint_G \frac{1}{\sqrt{2y-y^2}} \,dx \,dy$ with $G: x^2=4-2y$ in the first quadrant.

I solved the first part and have:$\int_0^2 \frac{\sqrt{4-2y}}{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}\,dy$. But now I'm stuck, how do I find the primitive of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. Observe that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{4-2y}}{\sqrt{2y-y^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\times\sqrt{2-y}}{\sqrt{y}\times\sqrt{2-y}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{y}}, \quad y \in (0,2).
$$